# How to modify this subquery to be more specific

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

A few weeks ago I made a question about this same query and got a great response which can be viewed here: [A better way to modify this query so the subquery will be more specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059939/a-better-way-to-modify-this-query-so-the-subquery-will-be-more-specific)

It works great, but then I ran into another request which now seems even more difficult. There are ad zones that should allow multiple sizes. For example, some zone with the name 'b' should be able to allow a 728x90 ad or a 300x250 ad. If I try to modify the subquery by adding this zone twice with two different sizes, as such:

```
select 'b' as zone_name, 728 as width union all
select 'b' as zone_name, 300 as width
```

then the database will return both of them, which is not good. I cannot use conditions such as that the width can be 728 or smaller, because then a 468x60 ad might be returned, which is also not good.

In theory, a solution along the lines of

```
select 'b' as zone_name, (728 or 300) as width union all
```

would be an ideal one. But I assume that kind of behavior can not be simulated.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: why isn't it good for the db to return both? isn't that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
select b as name, case when b = 728 then '728' else '300' end as width
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a suggestion?